# Make a 3D tube curve that is flatter/ovalized along it's tangent

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]How can I make a tube that is flattened along it's tangent. For example, if the tube were folded, the two flat sides would be touching?

For example, in this image, where I extruded the curve and added depth, the curve is bending along the edge rather than bending along the flat side. I would like to extrude so the flat side is always aligned with the tangent of the curve at a given point.

Comment: Could you post a picture to better illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Kind of like a ribbon, when you bend/twist it, it bends along the flat part.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the tilt of each point to 'twist' the flat extrusion of the curve. The tilt property is visible in the Transform panel of the properties sidebar <kbd>N</kbd> or you can use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> within the 3DView

[image]

[image]